# Background-size (Mozilla Firefox)

Tags: css, firefox

Tenho o seguinte código

```
background-image: url(#minha0imagem#); 
background-size: contain; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

No Chrome fica do jeito que quero, no centro e tela toda. No firefox não.

Já tentei -moz, -webkit, já atualizei meu firefox.

Parece que a forma como o firefox trabalha com redimensionamento de imagem é diferente do chrome e mesmo usando CSS3 e HTML5 puro não consigo replicar os efeitos.

Comment: qual o comportamento você esta esperando que o `contain` tenha?

Comment: Talvez seja outra propriedade ou outro elemento HTML que está fazendo ficar errado no FF. Veja esse exemplo do W3SCHOOLS, veja se em ambos os navegadores aparece igual: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=contain

Comment: Já tentou remover o súfixo -image e especificar as posições e tamanhos na mesma propriedade de estilo? Talvez a versão desse Firefox reconheça assim... Infelizmente não posso exemplar agora porque meu notebook ñ está ligando e não sou mais familiar com CSS(3. Fica... complicado.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly o comportamento do contain é por característica da minha imagem, eu sei que para ter tela toda deveria ser usado o cover rs!

Comment: @GuilhermeBrancoStracini ambos os navegadores aparecem iguais no link que mandou.

Comment: @TheProHands tentei sim! Inclusive tentei colocar tudo apenas com background usando as características da propriedade.

Comment: @IsraelBastos testei no firefox e no firefox developer e seu código funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Galera muito obrigado, mas como eu não consegui acabei optando por outra solução, usei uma div, uma tag img com width e height e modifiquei pelo css os detalhes tirando o scroll lateral e horizontal (uma gambiarra rs) mas pelo menos o resultado foi o esperado.

Comment: Então realmente tem outra coisa causando a divergência no FF

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
background: url('sua_imagem.jpg')no-repeat center top;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Tentei e nada amigão! Mas valeu pela força, consegui de outra maneira mesmo, com uma "quase" gambiarra rs